# Python Matlplotlib errorbar: some errors disappear

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipython, errorbar

I have an ipython notebook plotting some data with errors, but some of the errorbars disappear. This happens although I can't see anything special about these values. Below is the notebook (sorry about the lenghty data entries; I couldn't think of another way to do it).

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set_style('white')

hc_8=[0.99081659425686,
 0.0035807724071579,
 0.0036486661148434,
 3.0547067251442e-06,
 0.0015136562002304,
 0.00034601911991988,
 2.3401520791956e-05,
 2.8030427194401e-06,
 4.1162970805351e-07,
 9.1710776665829e-06,
 3.9398815871864e-05,
 4.4231786885767e-06,
 3.0956459298453e-06,
 1.9419348974675e-06,
 2.379397685075e-06,
 1.0845508880187e-06,
 1.9124426053082e-06,
 4.7226066879174e-07,
 5.0716363115017e-07,
 1.1081894051419e-07,
 7.9416431283342e-08,
 1.6516817308667e-08,
 4.0083862850936e-10,
 4.8319821836969e-09,
 3.0879304060312e-09,
 5.5671357273294e-09,
 7.7901130726092e-09,
 4.5657640815054e-09,
 1.5315424299983e-09,
 5.0188592345427e-12,
 2.2580896397634e-16]

err=[1.3891436413513369e-05,
0.00022700473730327057,
0.00023565165709769125,
0.00022395042167019547,
0.00022520816982478156,
0.00021206820520727488,
0.00020883185838967071,
0.00022300539245990713,
0.00020263881266942361,
0.00023012223590876285,
0.00020523181468988652,
0.00021127475414694269,
0.0002141613950092029, 
0.00021797460228818743,
0.00020896650606930448,
0.00021276389358642863,
0.00020295741658211708,
0.00020859865995398271,
0.00020952491755289146,
0.00020778891525548087,
0.00020883041033686742,
0.00020857100040878364,
0.00021691461288560443,
0.00021097629480290188,
0.00021374762124668886,
0.00021762787011087484,
0.00020798570342631768,
0.00020122385574404927,
0.00021145231450991181,
0.00020765816085479546,
0.00020825571752454633,
]

est=[  0.99540256998784726,    
  0.059895785850035944,   
  0.060507793561101343,   
  0.0019710971494187042,  
  0.038830929139159573,   
  0.018463774904873824,   
  0.0046955069297555064,  
  0.0018584056664347954,  
  0.00063659331149786968, 
  0.003331948609242674,   
  0.0064292492371676117,  
  0.0019628802580232119,  
  0.0015988809382858425,  
  0.0012577120684287974,  
  0.0015627879286385835,  
  0.0011401786365524927,  
  0.0014221828073456471,  
  0.0005458833011298159,  
  0.00071437837062369601, 
  0.00050896558455221718, 
  0.00019130332782904246, 
  0.0002061834214904301,  
  0.00010039647103085978, 
  0.00012180387323482591, 
  0.00025158959610823355, 
  0.00018180584721990496, 
  0.00021304933054298641, 
  0.00034851765573331136, 
  0.00026406529377739186, 
  0.00030970220238261107, 
  0.00015124475822489244, 
]


plt.plot(range(31),np.sqrt(hc_8),marker="^",ls='none',ms=10,mew=0,color='g')

plt.errorbar(range(31),est,yerr=err,marker="s",ls='none',fillstyle='none',ms=9,mew=1.3,color='r')

plt.yscale('log') 
fig=plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10)
plt.axis([-1,32,1e-5,1.1])
```

The output looks like below, note the missing errorbars (e.g. the very last):

[image: Errorplot]

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. I pasted your code into a notebook and it worked fine. See [here](http://imgur.com/iEcmysD)

Comment: I have seen something similar before when I have had errorbars go negative on a log plot, but that doesn't appear to be the case here

Comment: Huh that is weird.. Pasting my code above into a new notebook I again have the same problem. Could there be a difference in versions etc?

Comment: Not sure. In case it helps, I'm on a mac, with `python 2.7.10`, `numpy 1.9.2`, `matplotlib 1.4.3`, `seaborn 0.6.0` all installed by `macports`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone drops by here: a fix is to replace

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

with

```
plt.yscale('log', nonposy="clip")
```